# Products with no options are having the product quantity input hidden

Tags: bigcommerce

I have a Big Commerce store that has several products. Most of the products have options such as size and color which are working fine. A few products have no options and on those products the product-quantity input is being hidden after the page loads.

If I go into Advanced Options > Inventory > General Settings and set "When an option is out of stock" to "Hide the option" the product quantity becomes visible again and the product can be added to cart. I don't think this is a good solution because then products with options that are actually out of stock will still be available.

Any help that you can provide me would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Hey there, this seems like more of a product support question. Have you reached out to BigCommerce tech support to check the settings configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if you have the following option in your Config.JSON file.

```
"show_product_quantity_box": true/false
```

If you do, just set it to true. If this is not the case, did you try to manually display the quantity box/input with SCSS ?